# Mirroring column in one excel sheet to other multiple excel sheets with automatic updating

Tags: excel, vba, mirror, worksheet

I have an excel workbook that contains multiple sheets within it. For the sake of this question, the sheets are named Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, and so on. I would like to have Column A from sheet1 be replicated throughout the rest of the sheets and as new cells are added to column A in sheet1, they would automatically be entered into the other sheets within the workbook. I would prefer not to have a set "ending range; ie: A100000" for this. For example, if I enter First in cell A1 of Sheet1, the word "First" should now also appear in cell A1 of Sheet2. I have used the following code, and it does not seem to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
        Call UpdateFromSheet1
End Sub

Sub UpdateFromSheet1(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    If Sh.CodeName = "Sheet1" Then
        If Not Intersect(Target(1, 1), Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
            Sh.Range("A1:A1000").Copy Sheet2.Range("A1")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you not do this formulaically by setting the value (use Col A as an example) in the subsequent sheets to be `"=Sheet1!A1"` and copy that formula down a sufficient number of rows and cols?

Comment: You're not passing the Target parameter (or the Sh parameter) on to UpdatefromSheet.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

For a clean looking **Non-VBA** solution, you can use the formula references that others have mentioned, but enter it like this.

In Sheet2 cell A1 = `If(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!A1)` That way you can fill down on the whole of column A and not have "0" pop-up if Sheet1 has a rows without data.

I think you have the general idea, but I suspect you may not have your code in the right place.

For the **VBA** solution:

**First**, you don't need to call the sub from `Worksheet_Change` event (unless of course you want to use this sub for other reasons and pass variables to it. **Second**, if you place this code in the worksheet object in the VBE of the "Sheet1" it will do as you wish:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Not Intersect(Target, Columns("A")) Is Nothing Then

    Dim wks As Worksheet
    For Each wks In Sheets(Array("Sheet2", "Sheet3"))

        Target.EntireColumn.Copy wks.Columns(1)

    Next

End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very basic use for excel. You can set cells equal to each other. You in no way would need a VBA macro for this.

If you put this in cell "A1" on Sheet2 and Sheet3:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

Then when you type something into A1, it will be "mirrored" on sheets 2 and 3. You can autofill this down to all the cells in column A on sheets 2 and 3.

Are you familiar with the term *autofill*?

If you don't understand anything I just said and you want to just run a macro then run this and start typing away:

```
Sub MacroBasicQuestion()

Dim wbk As Workbook
Set wbk = ThisWorkbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet
Set ws1 = wbk.Sheets(1)
Set ws2 = wbk.Sheets(2)
Set ws3 = wbk.Sheets(3)

Dim cell As Range

Set cell = ws2.Range("A1:A1")
ws2.Select
cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!RC"
cell.Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A:A"), Type:=xlFillDefault

Set cell = ws3.Range("A1:A1")
ws3.Select
cell.FormulaR1C1 = "=Sheet1!RC"
cell.Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A:A"), Type:=xlFillDefault

End Sub
```

Good Luck.

Comment: The autofill doesn't work properly if rows or colums in the source sheet - the new rows do not appear in the "mirrored" sheet.